# Checking if string is numeric in dart

Tags: string, numbers, dart, isnumeric

I need to find out if a string is numeric in dart. It needs to return true on any valid number type in dart. So far, my solution is

```dart
bool isNumeric(String str) {
  try{
    var value = double.parse(str);
  } on FormatException {
    return false;
  } finally {
    return true;
  }
}
```

Is there a native way to do this? If not, is there a better way to do it?

Answer (score 129, accepted):

This can be simpliefied a bit

```dart
void main(args) {
  print(isNumeric(null));
  print(isNumeric(''));
  print(isNumeric('x'));
  print(isNumeric('123x'));
  print(isNumeric('123'));
  print(isNumeric('+123'));
  print(isNumeric('123.456'));
  print(isNumeric('1,234.567'));
  print(isNumeric('1.234,567'));
  print(isNumeric('-123'));
  print(isNumeric('INFINITY'));
  print(isNumeric(double.INFINITY.toString())); // 'Infinity'
  print(isNumeric(double.NAN.toString()));
  print(isNumeric('0x123'));
}

bool isNumeric(String s) {
  if(s == null) {
    return false;
  }
  return double.parse(s, (e) => null) != null;
}
```

```bash
false   // null  
false   // ''  
false   // 'x'  
false   // '123x'  
true    // '123'  
true    // '+123'
true    // '123.456'  
false   // '1,234.567'  
false   // '1.234,567' (would be a valid number in Austria/Germany/...)
true    // '-123'  
false   // 'INFINITY'  
true    // double.INFINITY.toString()
true    // double.NAN.toString()
false   // '0x123'
```

from double.parse DartDoc

```dart
   * Examples of accepted strings:
   *
   *     "3.14"
   *     "  3.14 \xA0"
   *     "0."
   *     ".0"
   *     "-1.e3"
   *     "1234E+7"
   *     "+.12e-9"
   *     "-NaN"
```

This version accepts also hexadecimal numbers

```dart
bool isNumeric(String s) {
  if(s == null) {
    return false;
  }

  // TODO according to DartDoc num.parse() includes both (double.parse and int.parse)
  return double.parse(s, (e) => null) != null || 
      int.parse(s, onError: (e) => null) != null;
}

print(int.parse('0xab'));
```

> true

**UPDATE**

Since `{onError(String source)}` is deprecated now you can just use `tryParse`:

```dart
bool isNumeric(String s) {
 if (s == null) {
   return false;
 }
 return double.tryParse(s) != null;
}
```

Comment: Since the question didn't define what it meant to be numeric, this is definitely a solution, but notice that it will accept `"Infinity"` and `"NaN"` as well. Whether initial '-' should be allowed also depends on the exact definition. If it must also accept `"0x123"`, you can use `num.parse` instead of `double.parse`.

Comment: Thanks for the hint! I considered asking what should be considered a number. You are right of course. Interesting that `"INFINITY"` is not considered a number but `"NaN"` is.

Comment: It only accepts exactly the output of `double.INFINITY.toString()`, which is "Infinity" (capitalized, but not upper-case).

Comment: Thanks! This is definitely a better solution than mine.

Comment: one liner: `bool isNumeric(String s) => s != null && double.tryParse(s) != null;`

Comment: I found the `isNumeric` function so handy that I modified it a bit and put it in a String extension:
`bool isDouble() { return double.tryParse(this) != null; }`

Answer (score 64):

In Dart 2 this method is deprecated

`int.parse(s, onError: (e) => null)`

instead, use

```
 bool _isNumeric(String str) {
    if(str == null) {
      return false;
    }
    return double.tryParse(str) != null;
  }
```

Answer (score 26):

for anyone wanting a non native way using regex

```
/// check if the string contains only numbers
 bool isNumeric(String str) {
        RegExp _numeric = RegExp(r'^-?[0-9]+$');
return _numeric.hasMatch(str);
}
```

Comment: It´s the easiest to apply. 
I would suggest to put _numeric inside of the functions, because this way it should be plugAndPlay.

The result should be:


 bool isNumeric(String str) {

RegExp _numeric = RegExp(r'^-?[0-9]+$');

return _numeric.hasMatch(str);
}

Comment: Most flexible and universal solution out there !

Answer (score 24):

Even shorter. Despite the fact it will works with `double` as well, using `num` is more accurately.

```
isNumeric(string) => num.tryParse(string) != null;
```

`num.tryParse` inside:

```
static num tryParse(String input) {
  String source = input.trim();
  return int.tryParse(source) ?? double.tryParse(source);
}
```

Answer (score 14):

```
if (int.tryParse(value) == null) {
  return 'Only Number are allowed';
}
```

Answer (score 6):

Yes, there is a more "sophisticated" way *rsrs*.

```
extension Numeric on String {
  bool get isNumeric => num.tryParse(this) != null ? true : false;
}

main() {
  print("1".isNumeric); // true
  print("-1".isNumeric); // true
  print("2.5".isNumeric); // true
  print("-2.5".isNumeric); // true
  print("0x14f".isNumeric); // true
  print("2,5".isNumeric); // false
  print("2a".isNumeric); // false
}
```

Comment: Can be written as follows to avoid redundancy   

extension Numeric on String {
  bool get isNumeric => num.tryParse(this) != null ;
}

Answer (score 3):

```
bool isOnlyNumber(String str) {
  try{
    var value = int.parse(str);
    return true;
  } on FormatException {
    return false;
  } 
}
```

Comment: It would be nice to give a brief explanation of how this works / how it solves the problem, and how it's different than existing answers.

Answer (score 0):

```
import 'dart:convert';

void main() {
  //------------------------allMatches Example---------------------------------
  print('Example 1');

  //We want to extract ages from the following string:
  String str1 = 'Sara is 26 years old. Maria is 18 while Masood is 8.';

  //Declaring a RegExp object with a pattern that matches sequences of digits
  RegExp reg1 = new RegExp(r'(\d+)');

  //Iterating over the matches returned from allMatches
  Iterable allMatches = reg1.allMatches(str1);
  var matchCount = 0;
  allMatches.forEach((match) {
    matchCount += 1;
    print('Match ${matchCount}: ' + str1.substring(match.start, match.end));
  });

  //------------------------firstMatch Example---------------------------------
  print('\nExample 2');

  //We want to find the first sequence of word characters in the following string:
  //Note: A word character is any single letter, number or underscore
  String str2 = '#%^!_as22 d3*fg%';

  //Declaring a RegExp object with a pattern that matches sequences of word
  //characters
  RegExp reg2 = new RegExp(r'(\w+)');

  //Using the firstMatch function to display the first match found
  Match firstMatch = reg2.firstMatch(str2) as Match;
  print('First match: ${str2.substring(firstMatch.start, firstMatch.end)}');

  //--------------------------hasMatch Example---------------------------------
  print('\nExample 3');

  //We want to check whether a following strings have white space or not
  String str3 = 'Achoo!';
  String str4 = 'Bless you.';

  //Declaring a RegExp object with a pattern that matches whitespaces
  RegExp reg3 = new RegExp(r'(\s)');

  //Using the hasMatch method to check strings for whitespaces
  print(
      'The string "' + str3 + '" contains whitespaces: ${reg3.hasMatch(str3)}');
  print(
      'The string "' + str4 + '" contains whitespaces: ${reg3.hasMatch(str4)}');

  //--------------------------stringMatch Example-------------------------------
  print('\nExample 4');

  //We want to print the first non-digit sequence in the following strings;
  String str5 = '121413dog299toy01food';
  String str6 = '00Tom1231frog';

  //Declaring a RegExp object with a pattern that matches sequence of non-digit
  //characters
  RegExp reg4 = new RegExp(r'(\D+)');

  //Using the stringMatch method to find the first non-digit match:
  String? str5Match = reg4.stringMatch(str5);
  String? str6Match = reg4.stringMatch(str6);
  print('First match for "' + str5 + '": $str5Match');
  print('First match for "' + str6 + '": $str6Match');

  //--------------------------matchAsPrefix Example-----------------------------
  print('\nExample 5');

  //We want to check if the following strings start with the word "Hello" or not:
  String str7 = 'Greetings, fellow human!';
  String str8 = 'Hello! How are you today?';

  //Declaring a RegExp object with a pattern that matches the word "Hello"
  RegExp reg5 = new RegExp(r'Hello');

  //Using the matchAsPrefix method to match "Hello" to the start of the strings
  Match? str7Match = reg5.matchAsPrefix(str7);
  Match? str8Match = reg5.matchAsPrefix(str8);
  print('"' + str7 + '" starts with hello: ${str7Match != null}');
  print('"' + str8 + '" starts with hello: ${str8Match != null}');
}
```

Comment: You can Better know about RegExp in this above example and you can find the matches with your strings.

Answer (score 0):

Building on Matso Abgaryan's answer and Günter Zöchbauer's updated answer,

I can get a ',' (comma) on my numeric soft keyboard while developing mobile apps in flutter, and `double.tryParse()` can return `Nan` as well as `null` - so checking vs null is not enough if a user can enter a comma on a soft numeric keyboard. If a string is empty, using `double.tryParse()` will produce `null` - so that edge case will be caught using this function;

```
bool _isNumeric(String str) {
   if (str == null) {
     return false;
   }
   return double.tryParse(str) is double; 
}
```

[Documentation for tryParse()](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/dart-core/double/tryParse.html)

Answer (score 0):

> In s1, s2, s3, if we want to convert the number to a string, the usage is displayed.
> In s4, s5, s6, if we want to convert a string that we don't know can be a number.
> In s6, if it cannot convert the value into a number, it returns 0. To prevent logical errors during program execution.

```
  test('Test', () async {

  var s1 = 3.parse(String);// "3"
  var s2 = "3".parse(String);// "3"
  var s3 = "3aaa".parse(String); "3aaa"

  var s4 = 3.parse(int);// 3
  var s5 = "3".parse(int);// 3
  var s6 = "3aaa".parse(int);// 0

  expect(true, true, reason: '');

 });

 



extension Ex on dynamic {
dynamic parse(Type t) {
  return (int == t)?
  (double.tryParse((this.toString())) != null)?
  int.parse(this.toString()): 0:
  (this.toString());
  }
}
```

Comment: Please add some explanation to your answer such that others can learn from it. Also, please never share code embedded in an image

Comment: If we used the int.parse code in the s6 example, we would fail when running the project. But in this example, because he knows that this is not possible, he replaced the value with zero.

Answer (score -1):

```
bool isNumeric(String s) {
  double? numeric = double.tryParse(s);

  if (numeric == null) {
    return false;
  } else {
    return true;
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your interest in contributing to the Stack Overflow community. This question already has quite a few answers—including one that has been extensively validated by the community. Are you certain your approach hasn’t been given previously? **If so, it would be useful to explain how your approach is different, under what circumstances your approach might be preferred, and/or why you think the previous answers aren’t sufficient.** Can you kindly [edit] your answer to offer an explanation?